# How to combine information from two tables when creating a JSON on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

What is the best approach to combine information from two different tables on Ruby on Rails, when building a JSON for Web Services purpose?

I want to combine my list of clients with a tag that is taken from another table than users table.

Here is how I proceed from the controller

```
def clients
    @orders = @bar.orders
    @users = User.where(id: @orders.pluck(:user_id).uniq).all
    @tags = UserTag.where(bar: @bar, user_id: @orders.pluck(:user_id).uniq).all
end
```

The view is built this way

```
json.user_tags do
    json.array!(@tags) do |user_tag|
        json.extract! user_tag, :id, :bar_id, :user_id, :tag
    end
end

json.users do
  json.array!(@users) do |user|
      json.extract! user, :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :facebook_id, :context, :created_at, :updated_at, :company, :phone, :birthdate, :stripe_customer_id, :bar_id, :role
  end
end
```

The JSON generated with this code looks like this

[image]

I would like to integrate the tag field directly in users array, next to other users information such as on this illustration

[image]

The UserTag model is built like that

```
class UserTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :bar
  validates_uniqueness_of :bar_id, :user_id, :scope => :bar_id
  acts_as_paranoid without_default_scope: true

  def self.default_scope
    with_deleted
  end

  def api_error_message
    errors.full_messages.join("\n")
  end

end
```

And User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :access_tokens, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :club
    belongs_to :bar
    enum role: [:user, :club_owner, :waiter, :admin]

    has_many :club_comments
    has_many :club_subscriptions
    has_many :artist_subscriptions
    has_many :artist_votes
    has_many :payments
    has_many :carts
    has_many :user_entrances
    has_many :bookings, through: :user_entrances
    has_many :booking_events, through: :user_entrances
    has_many :cart_item_consumptions
    has_many :clientlist_elements

    has_secure_password

    has_one :address, as: :addressable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

    validates :password, length: {minimum: 8}, if: :validate_password?
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, if: :validate_password?
    validates :email, presence: true, if: :user_context_email
    validates :email, email: true, if: :user_context_email
    validates :email, :facebook_id, uniqueness: true, :allow_blank => true, :allow_nil => true
    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :last_name, presence: true

    reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude

    after_create :create_access_token
    after_save :update_vote_position_if_needed

    def validate_password?
        password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
    end

    def name
        "#{first_name.capitalize} #{last_name.capitalize}"
    end

    def create_access_token
        AccessToken.create(user: self)
    end

    def user_context_email
        context == 0
    end

    def user_context_fb
        context == 1
    end

    def update_vote_position_if_needed
        if self.latitude_changed? || self.longitude_changed?
            self.delay.update_vote_position
        end
    end

    def update_vote_position
        self.artist_votes.each do |vote|
            vote.latitude = self.latitude
            vote.longitude = self.longitude
            vote.save
        end
    end

    def stripe_description
        "#{first_name} #{last_name} - #{email}"
    end

    def stripe_customer_metadata
        {"User_id" => self.id, "Firstname" => self.first_name, "Lastname" => self.last_name, "Email" => self.email, "Phone" => self.phone}
    end

    def api_error_message
        errors.full_messages.join("\n")
    end

end
```

**EDIT**

I tried the @krishnar solution, here is how the JSON looks like now

[image]

The users are duplicated and only users with tag appear (we need to display all users even those without tags)

Comment: model association between User and UserTag?

Comment: @krishnar, I updated the post to show the User+UserTag models

Comment: What if multiple tags present for same user?  how will u show tag_id inside user hash?

Comment: There is only one tag allowed by bar+user, as you can see in UserTag model: validates_uniqueness_of :bar_id, :user_id, :scope => :bar_id

Comment: what about user to user_tag association?

Comment: I am testing now this option, I added "has_many :user_tags" to User model

Comment: check answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify user model to have association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # define user to user_tags association
  has_many :user_tags
end
```

Join users table with user_tags and select user_tags id as tag to use in json file:

```
def clients
    @orders = @bar.orders
    @users = User.where(id: @orders.pluck(:user_id).uniq).joins("left join user_tags on users.id=user_tags.user_id and user_tags.bar_id='#{@bar.id}'").select("users.*","user_tags.id as tag")
    @tags = UserTag.where(bar: @bar, user_id: @orders.pluck(:user_id).uniq).all
end
```

Now you can access tag in @users array:

```
json.users do
  json.array!(@users) do |user|
      json.extract! user, :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :facebook_id, :context, :created_at, :updated_at, :company, :phone, :birthdate, :stripe_customer_id, :bar_id, :role, :tag
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem with this solution is that only users with tag are displayed, and I want to display all (even those without tag). And also the users are duplicated

Comment: @118218   which rails version u using?

Comment: I am using 2.2.4

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I only changed "user_tags.id" to "user_tags.tag" in clients method to fit it to my usecase